# How to create file using streamwriter in c# in which the content is inputed by users using cmd

Tags: c#, cmd

I created a console application which accepts arguments. After building the program i will run it through cmd in which the user will input like this "filemgr.exe create [filename] [contents]" . My code is below. I want to enter "my text here" content, but when i check the output, only the FIRST word is displayed which is the "my", how to include the rest of the strings?(which is the text here)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace filemgr
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args[0]=="create")
            {
                using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(args[1]))
                {
                    file.Write(args[2]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Space in the separator of console parameters, if you want to pass phrase with space as single param you should surround the phrase with double quotes :

MyExecutable.exe "Param1 gose here" Param2

Comment: is it possible not to use double quotes? is it programmable in c# in making phrase with spaces as single param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recombine the args array into a string (although this method will likely lose quotes):

```
file.Write(string.Join(" ", args.Skip(2)));
```

Alternatively you can quote the string in the commandline:

```
program.exe create test.txt "hello this is a message"
```

Also, if you want to *append* to the file through sequential calls you need to open the stream like so:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(args[1], true))
```

This signifies that you want append mode, and not create/replace.

Answer (score 1):

Pass content args in double quotes

```
filemgr.exe create [filename] "[contents]"

filemgr.exe create C:\test.txt "my file content"
```

I would suggest to use quotes even in file path as well. When you use `args`, its always a chance to make mistake while accessing arguments.